# How to handle nullable column in table join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null

I have a situation where I am trying to find properties that were valid within a version.  I have a Version table and Property table below. The Property records have a version they were introduced in and removed in.

I am trying to select the properties that are between the introduced and removed in.  Removed in is null however and that messes my join up.  I have compensated (in an ugly manner) with the SQL below.  If the removed in is null I set it the max value for int.  This works but it would be nice that when the Removed In is null to ignore the second qualification in the join.  Any thoughts?

```
**Version**
    id      Name
    ---     -----------------
    1           VersionA
    2           VersionB

**Property**
    id          Name                IntroducedInVersion     RemovedInVersion
    ---         -----------------   -------------------     -----------------
    1               Property1       1                       null
    2               Property2       1                       2


SELECT 
    p.PropertyName
    ,p.IntroducedInVersion
    ,p.RemovedInVersion
FROM
    Version v
    join Property p on p.IntroducedInVersion <= v.Id 
        and ISNULL(cp.RemovedInVersion, 2147483647) > v.Id
WHERE 
    v.Id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT 
  p.PropertyName
  ,p.IntroducedInVersion
  ,p.RemovedInVersion
FROM Version v
join Property p
  on (RemovedInVersionp is null
    and v.id > IntroducedInVersion)
    or
    v.id between IntroducedInVersion
         and RemovedInVersion - 1
WHERE  v.Id = 1
```

But I think it would not perform as well as your original query.

A better option is this:

```
SELECT 
  p.PropertyName
  ,p.IntroducedInVersion
  ,p.RemovedInVersion
FROM Version v
join Property p
  on v.id between IntroducedInVersion
       and ifnull(RemovedInVersion - 1, v.id)
WHERE v.Id = 1
```

Which works because a value is equal to itself, so it will be "between" itself and another value.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian I think that will work if I changed this "ifnull(RemovedInVersion, v.id)" to "ifnull(RemovedInVersion - 1, v.id)". I don't want the RemovedInVersion to be inclusive.